# Cannot install app to tablet via Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an ASUS Memo Pad 7 with Android 4.2.2, and for some reason, I cannot install apps to it via Android Studio, it works on other devices so its probably something with the device.

When I in Android Studio click the Play icon, it begins its gradle build and installation etc. and ends up with the message of "Install successfully finished in 1s 23 ms" .. But nothing happens on the device. Even if I open the app on the device (installed from Google Play Store), before I start the installation from Android Studio, it doesn't even close the app or anything. It was also like this before i had it installed via Google Play Store.

I don't what to do. I've enabled USB Debugging in developer settings.. But what else there i can do?

If i check logcat i get the followin output:

```
07-01 14:52:47.033 26411-26411/? E/dalvikvm: Class lookup Ljava/lang/Daemons; attempted with exception pending
07-01 14:52:47.045 26411-26411/? E/dalvikvm: VM aborting
07-01 14:52:47.045 26411-26411/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 26411 (app_process)
07-01 14:52:47.598 26415-26415/? E/dalvikvm: Class lookup Ljava/lang/Daemons; attempted with exception pending
07-01 14:52:47.609 26415-26415/? E/dalvikvm: VM aborting
07-01 14:52:47.610 26415-26415/? A/libc: Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xdeadd00d (code=1), thread 26415 (app_process)
```

Comment: Maybe  your app crash when launched.

Comment: @maryam - It works fine on other devices i have. Its only this tablet in particular. I've even tried to completely factory reset it, still no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this particular instance i think it had something to do with the tablet being rooted via the installed Rom. Since factory resetting it didn't help, i instead flashed a non-rooted stock rom back onto the device, and now it is working again